# Open application depending on connected network

Tags: networking, windows-10, boot

As my school's WiFi blocks Onedrive, it is useless to open it during startup.

Therefore, my question is, can an app be opened only when connected to a certain WiFi access point using Windows 10 Home Edition?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @mtak Windows 10 Home Edition

Comment: There is no "constant monitoring" mechanism for this purpose because it's just unnecessary in most cases. You may want to write a scheduled task or your own service that runs in the system tray and when yoru computer connects to a specific SSID closes the OneDrive app. Additionally, is it really worth going as far as stopping the OneDrive app for the sake of it not syncing whilst at school?

Comment: @Kinnectus thank you for the suggestions. As for is it worth it, when saving word docs, pop ups keep appearing which state the document hasn't been synced, which is very annoying.